# Creating two different profiles in one application

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a BlogApp App and I have two different sections, One is `Blog Section` and another is `Article Section`.
AND i am trying to create two different profiles for them.

When a user register or signup then a `Profile` is successfully creating for Blog Section ( NOT Article section ). BUT i am trying to do :- `When user click on` Article section `after signup then there will be option of creating another Profile for Article Section` and both will be different profile. ( AND there will be no relation between `Blog` Profile and `Article` Profile BUT user will same )

Blog Profile is successfully creating BUT I am trying to make Article Profile.

models.py

```
class ArticleProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,default='',null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='')
```

views.py

```
def create_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArticleProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            custom_form = form.save(False)
            custom_form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Article Profile is Created")
            return redirect('dating:DatingSection')

    else:
        form = ArticleProfileForm(instance=request.user)

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'dating/create_profile.html', context)
```

BUT when i create profile using this form then it is not saving in Admin.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
form = ArticleProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=request.user)
                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You are passing `User` as instance where the ArticleProfileForm creates `ArticleProfile` instance. So you need to remove that part of the code. And update the code like this:

```
form = ArticleProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
    custom_form = form.save(False)
    custom_form.user = request.user  # change here
    custom_form.save()
```

If still the problem persists, try renderning the [form errors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors) to pin point what is exactly wrong here.

Comment: Thanks for your Help. It already solved BUT how can i seperate two different profile ? I will really appreciate your Help

Comment: I would say, rather than keeping two different models, use one. Then you can use choice field to make it different. Or consider using [Proxy Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#proxy-models).

Comment: You mean, I should make only one `Profile`. BUT can you explain me what do you mean by `choice field` in seperating them ?

Comment: BUT i don't want to ask user to select profile while registrations **instead** if user is interested in `Article Section` then user can create one

Comment: You can add a field with [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#choices), like `[('blog', 'Blog'), ('article', 'Article')]`, and add that choice before `custom_form.save()`. In that way you can easily expend your model in future with minimal changes in code.